# Why will the bullets sometimes not show up in the game view when the player shoots?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I press the shoot button, which I have mapped to space, the bullets sometimes won't appear on the game view but will appear in the scene view. There is nothing in front of the bullets causing them not to appear. I have noticed that this occurs at specific coordinates,  (-4.06, -8.15), (2.6, -8.15), (4.5, -8.15), (3.9, .8.15) are some of the rough coordinates that the bullets won't show in the game view.
Video of ploblem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWgjb.jpg

Bullet script:

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.up * speed;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log(collision.name);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Turret script:

```
public class Turret : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: This must have to do with the camera because you don’t view through the camera for scene view. Did you change any, any at all, settings in the camera?

Comment: A few things, could be camera settings, clip plane is clipping them (depending on your camera settings), they could be impacting the player object and just stopping (it's hard to see on the video as the quality isn't great and the shots are tiny).

Comment: @ken What do you mean? I am using a camera in the scene view. I have tried moving the camera but that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Try [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/681882/game-object-is-visible-in-scene-tabbut-not-in-the.html).

Comment: Inspect one of the missing bullets in the hierarchy to see where that game object actually is.

Comment: The problem was fixed by changing the width of the bullet.

Comment: Why did changing the width of the bullet bring the bullet back into view?

Comment: Not sure what we are supposed to see in the video .. I could see bullets being fired ... I didn't note a bullet that was present in the SceneView but not in the GameView .. Also you should at some point destroy the bullets ^^ you are spamming your Hierarchy with objects that will never be seen again ^^